# gstreamer WARNING: erroneous pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

I am currently getting the following error 
`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "Qtdemux"` when I run the following command

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=~/Desktop/Dog.mp4 ! Qtdemux ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I have tried making sure I have gstreamer-plugin-good and get the following response
`gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4)`.

However when I look at `gst-inspect-1.0 Qtdemux` I get the following response `No such element or plugin 'Qtdemux'`.

Any thoughts on what may be the problem I am facing?

Comment: Try running gst-inspect | grep <element-name*> , to find out the exact name of the element you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is `qtdemux`, with a samll `q`.